# Can the last modification date of standalone.xml file be changed alone?

Tags: windows-server-2012, files, jboss, wildfly8

In our production envirement ***(jboss wildfly 8.2),*** Windows server 2012 R2, I noticed that all of the date of creation, modification and access of the configuration file ***Standalone.xml*** was changed to the same date. I took a look at the event log to know who has accessed the this server at this time. I didn't find any access.

My question is, who is responsible for this change? Can these dates be changed by the application or some non-human task, service ...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standalone.xml file gets backed up and rewritten to the file system on startup. This is documented here, for AS7, I assume this feature has not changed since then.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Configuration+file+history

You should have a directory called 'standalone_xml_history' in the same place, containing recent backups of the file.